# How to uninstall python and all packages on mac?

Tags: python

I would like to uninstall all the python version installed and all packages on my MAC.

The python version I get is the following:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

However, I have `Python 2.7` folder in Applications.

I also have installed Anaconda and the folder

```
/Users/myName/anaconda3
```

I would to uninstall `Python 3.7.3` and all the packages I have installed both trough `pypi` and trough `conda`

Comment: so you want to kill python3 and go with python2? but why?

Comment: use pip uninstall, i'm also recommend to use virtual environment

Comment: @kederrac I would like to unistall al the packages I have installed for python3. I thought the easiest way is to unistall it  and reinstall python3

Comment: Here is a useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790090/8446061

Answer (score 0):

I,once, deleted a python version completely from my mac by doing the following steps on the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf “/Applications/Python”
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python
```

Then, when the password is prompted, enter it and confirm.

As, for anaconda, I remember deleting it once due to a problem using this software here:
https://nektony.com/mac-app-cleaner/download?productname=Anaconda

It's a download link, so be careful before you click incase you are thinking it contains information about the software etc.

My python version was 3.something, so I am not exactly sure whether it will help with the latest one but I thought my steps might help so I hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

I did what Mahir said above, but I had Python 3.9 and the 3.8 that Anaconda had installed. I've uninstalled 3.9, but I couldn't find the folder where the 3.8 was. After some time I've found it inside the Command Line folder in this path here:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Then I deleted all the files/folders related to python with the command below:

```
sudo rm -rf pip3 pip3.8 pydoc3 pydoc3.8 python3 python3.8
```

Maybe you'll also have to do this to get rid of python